# Can't use Virtualenv on mac anymore

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am having a problem when trying to initiate a new `virtualenv`. It has stopped working suddenly and I don't know what to do.

This is the error I get when i try to create a `virtualenv` named "test" as an example:

```
Lucas-Rezendes-MacBook:Desktop lucas$ virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
install_name_tool: for architecture cputype (16777223) cpusubtype (-2147483645) object: test/bin/python malformed object (unknown load command 4)
Could not call install_name_tool -- you must have Apple's development tools installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 810, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 901, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1166, in install_python
    py_executable])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 878, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Fram.../Versions/2.7/Python @executable_path/../.Python test/bin/python failed with error code 1
Lucas-Rezendes-MacBook:Desktop lucas$
```

I already reinstalled Xcode (newest version) twice only today!
I also did "which python" which retuned /opt/local/bin/python and when I try to create using "virtualenv -p /opt/local/bin/python test" I get this error:

Lucas-Rezendes-MacBook:bin lucas$ virtualenv -p /opt/local/bin/python test
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/local/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 2270, in 
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1029, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1154, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 399, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test'
Lucas-Rezendes-MacBook:bin lucas$

I really don't know what else to do. Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/7 has some solutions - including the fact that the install from the app store only installs the installer (?!).

Comment: Even after I had opened the Xcode in my apps folder (and it has installed something about mobile idk what), I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://blog.cingusoft.org/mac-osx-lion-virtualenv-and-could-not-call-in
Since Xcode 4.3.1, command-line-tools like install_name_tool is not installed automatically, so you will have to do it yourself. You will need to register an apple developer ID.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing xcode dev tools by running

```
xcode-select –-install
```